# View added u AddSubview Not showing in UI (Mac OS Mojave)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac, macos-mojave

We have a NSview in the homePage of our application.Where we add a Nsviewcontroller as subview.The Nsviewcontroller consists of a tableview with delegates. Here the tableview inside the viewcontroller is not displaying in the Nsview of home page.But the tableview row datas are binded succesfully and delagtes are also correctly hitting while using breakpoints.Also While debugging the view is not null.The issue is the User interface is not displaying.

I have created a Nsview programatically and tried to add as subview in homepage and it successfully works.

The functionality is correctly working in the Previous OSX versions. (The issue is only with Mac Os Mojave).

Below is the code :-

```
if (summaryVC == null) {
    summaryVC = new SummaryViewController ();
    }

 summaryVC.View.Frame = vwMain.Bounds;

vwMain.AddSubview (summaryVC.View);
CommonClass.SummaryController = summaryVC;
```

Note:-

SummaryViewController - Contains tableview and delegates.
 vwMain:- Nsview in the homepage.
 The issue is in the Mac Os application Developed by Xamarin.Mac

Please any one help me to solve the issue

Comment: A known issue with Mojave and Mono/Xamarin.Mac, a Apple radr issue has been posted but no known stable fix at this time : https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4509 I would add any additional information you have concerning the problem to the open issue in the issue I linked (All of my Xamarin.Mac projects are currently broken on Mojave due to UI rendering corruption)

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the latest beta release of xamarin.mac
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4848